# How to retrieve user data based on role using SQL?

Tags: database, user-roles, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to retrieve user data from SQL database and I have managed to do it with the SQL code given below:

```
SELECT 
    wpu6_users.display_name AS n_user_display_name,
    t1.meta_value AS n_user_first_name,
    t2.meta_value AS n_user_phone, 
    wpu6_users.user_email AS n_user_user_email,
    t3.meta_value AS n_user_address_1,
    t4.meta_value AS n_user_address_2,
    t5.meta_value AS n_user_area,
    t6.meta_value AS n_user_city,
    t7.meta_value AS n_user_state,
    t8.meta_value AS n_user_country,
    t9.meta_value AS n_user_postcode
    FROM wpu6_users
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t1 ON t1.user_id = wpu6_users.ID 
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t3 ON t2.user_id = t3.user_id  
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t4 ON t3.user_id = t4.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t5 ON t4.user_id = t5.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t6 ON t5.user_id = t6.user_id  
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t7 ON t6.user_id = t7.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t8 ON t7.user_id = t8.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wpu6_usermeta AS t9 ON t8.user_id = t9.user_id
    WHERE t1.meta_key = 'billing_first_name' 
    AND t2.meta_key = 'billing_phone' 
    AND t3.meta_key = 'billing_address_1' 
    AND t4.meta_key = 'billing_address_2'
    AND t5.meta_key = 'mv_area' 
    AND t6.meta_key = 'billing_city' 
    AND t7.meta_key = 'billing_state'
    AND t8.meta_key = 'billing_country' 
    AND t9.meta_key = 'billing_postcode'
```

Now I am trying to display users based on role using SQL. Can anyone suggest me on how to retrieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in `WHERE` condition of your SQL query.

```
WHERE t1.meta_key = "<?php echo $wpdb->prefix; ?>capabilities" 
AND ( t1.meta_value LIKE '%ROLE_YOU_WANT_TO_FILTER%')
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. I also tried with following code and it didn't work as well `WHERE t1.meta_key = 'wpu6_capabilities' 
AND t1.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'`